# When power is of form 0/0

Tags: continuity

In the following function
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{\frac{\tan 6x}{\tan 5x}},& \mbox{ if } 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
b+2,&\mbox{ if }x=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\left(1+|\cos x|\right)^{\frac{a|\tan x|}{b}},&\mbox{ if }\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi
\end{cases}
$$
We have to determine the values of $a$ & $b$ , if $f$ is continuous at $x=1/2\pi$.

I am confused how to solve the limit at LHL of $x=1/2\pi$ . As in there the power is of form $0/0$ . Could we use L hopital in these type of problem .

Comment: Do you mean at $x=\frac12\pi$?

Comment: I don't see $0/0$ anywhere in this problem. I recommend to edit the question, showing more of the details of your work on the problem--which limit you were working on, what fraction is going to $0/0,$ and so forth. And _use MathJax_ so that we can correctly read the math you're writing: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hint for Lhs limit

put $$t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$$

then $$f(x)=(\frac{6}{5})^{\frac{\tan( -6t)  }{ \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-5t  )}}$$

which goes to $1$.